# MAPI Client installed now Exchange 2010 not working

Tags: exchange-server

I have a Windows SBS 2011 server with Exchange 2010 installed. Recently I installed BackupAssist (www.backupassist.com) and configured a Exchange 2010 backup task. Then it asked for "Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client (and CDO) 1.2.1" installation and I proceeded. But after that installationen the Exchange Server stopped receiving messages?

In EventViewer I can read following errors:

```
Process MSExchangeFDS.exe (PID=10352). Failed to read property Path from metabase object IIS://DISERVER2.di2.local/W3SVC/1/ROOT/OAB. OAB synchronization suspended.
```

AND

```
An exception occurred and was handled by Exchange ActiveSync. This may have been caused by an outdated or corrupted Exchange ActiveSync device partnership. This can occur if a user tries to modify the same item from multiple computers. If this is the case, Exchange ActiveSync will re-create the partnership with the device. Items will be updated at the next synchronization. 

URL=/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/default.eas?User=nils.nilsson&DeviceId=Appl7R0466MBA4S&DeviceType=iPhone&Cmd=SendMail
--- Undantagets början ---
Undantagstyp: System.Web.HttpException
Undantagsmeddelande: Den maximala längden för begäran överskreds.
Undantagsnivå: 0
Stackdump:    vid System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   vid System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
   vid Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.AirSyncRequest.get_InputStream()
   vid Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Command.WorkerThread()
--- Undantagets slut ---.
```

I uninstalled "Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client (and CDO) 1.2.1" but the problem persists.

Do anybody know what I can do to solve this?

/Daniel

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 different, unrelated problems.

First problem fix:

Open the Exchange Powershell and type the following:

```
cd 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin'
.\UpdateCas.ps1
iisreset
```

Second problem fix;

Open Exchange and find the user 'nils.nilsson', right click his user and choose "Manage Mobile Phone" and then delete and association this user has with their active sync devices.

Comment: Hi Nathan and thank you. But this did not resolve my problem. The server still not receiving any external emails. I think there is some other problem causing exchange not receiving emails.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

After 15 hours I found that some other process snached port 25....

Run command: netstat -ano | findstr :25
and look for processID. If it is not your expected processID some other process has taken port 25 and Exchange can't receive emails.

/Daniel